# BeautifulSoup soup.find not returning values

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a set of pages for some profiles, and I built a scraper that iterates over a list of urls (ex:https://myurl.com) from a csv file and feeds them into beautiful soul. However, soup.find returns no values, despite working when only one URL is given.

For example this snippet works:

```
page = requests.get('www.myurl.org')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

name = soup.title.string
specialty = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Spec"})
birthdate = soup.find('p', attrs={'id' : "content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Birth"})
gender = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Gender"})
email = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Web"})

f.writerow([name, specialty, birthdate, gender, email])
```

however, this only returns the field "name" in csv, and none of the subsequent:

```
with open('linklistshort.csv') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        print(url)
        site = urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
        name = soup.title.string
        specialty = soup.find('p', attrs={'id' :"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Spec"})
        birthdate = soup.find('p', attrs={'id' : "content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Birth"})
        gender = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Gender"})
        email = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Web"})
        f.writerow([name, specialty, birthdate, gender, email])
```

The result should be a csv file with five columns, each including the correct data - and this is what I get from the first code block, for the individual url entered.

However, the actual output returns five columns, the first filled with the "name" field and the others blank. Clearly, looping through the URLs is working, since name is returning for each url. The only difference in the beautifulSoup command is that I have page.text in the first and only site, however site.text breaks the looping functionality and returns no output.

I'm a total python beginner, but I've troubleshot this via decode commands etc, and each time the loop fail if I change anything.

Comment: Could you give us the 2nd and 3rd urls that you want to parse?

Comment: To be able to help, we really need to see the actual URLs you are trying to scrape. That way we can see the HTML that is being returned and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing BeautifulSoup object in csv writerow function, please change all soup objects into text like this:

```
page = requests.get('www.myurl.org')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

name = soup.title.string
specialty = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Spec"}).text
birthdate = soup.find('p', attrs={'id' : "content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Birth"}).text
gender = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl17_Gender"}).text
email = soup.find('p', attrs={'id':"content_element_0_main_column_0_ctl09_Web"}).text

f.writerow([name, specialty, birthdate, gender, email])
```